# Numpy: How To Vectorize Operations?

Tags: numpy, vectorization, tensor

I have the following vectors

```
shape u_w: (50,)
shape Vt: (6, 50)
shape v: (50,)
```

and with them I perform the following calculations

```py
w = np.tanh(u_w + Vt[0])
w_squared = w ** 2
z = np.dot(v, w)
s = sigmoid(np.dot(v, w))

J = -np.log(sigmoid(z))
dv = np.dot(sigmoid(z) - 1, w)
du_w = np.dot(s - 1, v, (1 - w_squared))
dVt = np.dot(s - 1, v, (1 - w_squared))

for vt in Vt[1:]:
    t = np.tanh(u_w + vt)
    svt = sigmoid(np.dot(-v, t))

    J -= np.log(svt)
    dv -= np.dot((svt - 1), t)
    du_w -= np.dot((svt - 1), v, (1 - t**2))
    dVt = np.vstack((dVt, -np.dot(svt - 1, v, (1 - t**2))))
```

How do I vectorize the calculations for J, dv, du_w and dVt, so that they work for a batch of S items with the following shapes?

```
shape(u_w) => (512, 50)
shape(Vt)  => (512, 6, 50)
shape(v)   => (50,)
```

Comment: `np.matmul` and `np.einsum` can do the same as `np.dot` but for batches.  Read the docs.

Comment: Before trying to vectorize the code, you should certainly *factorize it*. For example, computing `np.tanh(u_w + Vt[0])` only once instead of 7 times. The same applies for `sigmoid(np.dot(v, np.tanh(u_w + Vt[0])))` computed 4 times. Not only it makes the code more readable and help us to understand the operations (and probably you too), but it also speed up a lot the execution of the code.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for the advice. I'm starting to work on it. And, btw, sorry for the really poorly written code. I'm getting started with python and numpy operations. Going to update the questions once I clean it up!